# build boost library

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost

i have boost librray 1.44.0 how can i  build it?i am using visual studio 2010 
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tool `bjam.exe` (just search for it in the www and download it).
When downloaded and extracted, just type `bjam toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete stage` from the windows console in your boost directory. Then reference the include and lib directories within Visual Studio:

- Include: `boost_1_44_0` (plus possibly `boost_1_44_0\boost`)
- Lib: `boost_1_44_0\stage\lib`

Comment: Thanks. That works. For browsing the code I would like to have a sln file. Is there such a thing for boost?

Comment: boost doesn't come with a sln file. Maybe anyone has already created one, I don't know. But I think it is probably the best, you create your own sln file.

Answer (score 0):

go to your boost directory (c:\boost or whatever) and run:
**bootstrap.bat**
and then 
**bjam.exe**

It should generate the .lib files in $BOOST\stage\lib (about 850 MB :P)