# How do I build boost with Visual Studio 2008 when I have multiple Visual Studio versions installed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, boost, bjam

I know how to build boost with the latest visual studio on my machine ([this question, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977555/build-boost-library))

However, I need to build the libs for Visual Studio 2008 (vc9)

I tried using toolset=vc9 but I get problems/no success.

How can I build the libs for vc9?

After I run boostrap I try running

```
b2 toolset=vc9
```

but the output is:

> C:/Development/boost
>   50/boost_1_50_0/boost_1_50_0/tools/build/v2/build\toolset.jam:39: in
>   toolset.using rule vc9.init unknown in module toolset
>
> C:/Development/boost
>   50/boost_1_50_0/boost_1_50_0/tools/build/v2\build-system.jam:481: in
>   process-explicit-toolset-requests
>
> C:/Development/boost
>   50/boost_1_50_0/boost_1_50_0/tools/build/v2\build-system.jam:562: in
>   load
>
> C:\Development\boost
>   50\boost_1_50_0\boost_1_50_0\tools\build\v2/kernel\modules.jam:283: in
>   import
>
> C:\Development\boost
>   50\boost_1_50_0\boost_1_50_0\tools\build\v2/kernel/bootstrap.jam:142:
>   in boost-build
>
> C:\Development\boost 50\boost_1_50_0\boost_1_50_0\boost-build.jam:17:
>   in module scope

Answer (score 23):

toolset=msvc-9.0

I have VS2008-Pro and VS2010-Express installed. The default ran with VS2010. Setting toolset=msvc-9.0 caused the build to run with VS2008. Using Boost 1.51.0.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to dig into the How-To-Build-Boost documentation, and in particular see [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#id44);
but the part you need to specify a particular MSVC version is pointed to [here](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/configuration.html).  That suggests creating a `user-config.jam`, which probably would work, but I created a `project-config.jam` file instead.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be able to do this by running the top-level boost build (or meta build) script from different VC command lines.  For example to build with VC2012, start a command line with vc 2012 vars.  And for 2010, do the same.  The automatically generated build scripts seem to do the right thing.

I am sure there are ways to do this by editing the build scripts myself or by setting the toolset, but I had no success with that.

Comment: This is exactly what I would have expected - if I try to build boost with the vs2008 command line, I want the vs2008 compiler and build environment. And boost doesn't do this - it goes ahead and chooses vs2010. The build system should be referentially transparent. What boost is doing - fishing around for global system settings - is just about the worst thing they could do.